# Parse div element from html with style attributes

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the text  `Something here I want to get`  inside the div element from a html file using Python and BeautifulSoup.

This is how part of the code looks like in html:

```
<div xmlns="" id="idp46819314579224" style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; margin: 0 0 10px 0; padding: 5px 10px; background: #d43f3a; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px; color: #fff;" class="" onclick="toggleSection('idp46819314579224-container');" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'">Something here I want to get<div id="idp46819314579224-toggletext" style="float: right; text-align: center; width: 8px;">
                -
            </div>
</div>
```

And this is how I tried to do:

```
vu = soup.find_all("div", {"style" : "background: #d43f3a"})

for div in vu:
    print(div.text)
```

I use loop because there are several div with different id but all of them has the same background colour. It has no errors, but I got no output.

How can I get the text using the background colour as the condition?

Comment: Does changing it to `background-color: #d43f3a` help?

Comment: It can be run, but still no output. Is it because it cannot use style as the condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `style` attribute has other content inside it

```
style="box-sizing: ....; ....;"
```

Your current code is asking `if style == "background: #d43f3a"` which it is not.

What you can do is ask `if "background: #d43f3a" in style` -- a sub-string check.

One approach is passing a [regular expression](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#the-keyword-arguments).

```
>>> import re
>>> vu = soup.find_all("div", style=re.compile("background: #d43f3a"))
... 
... for div in vu:
...     print(div.text.strip())
Something here I want to get
```

You can also say the same thing using [CSS Selectors](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#css-selectors)

```
soup.select('div[style*="background: #d43f3a"]')
```

Or by passing a function/lambda

```
>>> vu = soup.find_all("div", style=lambda style: "background: #d43f3a" in style)
... 
... for div in vu:
...     print(div.text.strip())
Something here I want to get
```